# How to reconcile units in accelerometer noise density

Tags: accelerometer, noise-spectral-density

I am trying to model an accelerometer in MATLAB. It is asking for the noise density in (m/s^2)/sqrt(Hz).  The datasheet for the IMU I am trying to model gives output noise in (m/s) for the 100Hz StdDev bandwidth.

How to I get the right units from this value?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, for accelerometers, IMU manufacturers give the noise spectral density in \$m/s^2/\sqrt {\text {Hz}}\$ units. I've found one datasheet on Web (Single Axis MEMS MA1002 High Performance MEMS Capacitive Accelerometer) that gives a total root mean squared noise in the frequency band 0.1Hz to 100Hz. Remarkably, this datasheet also gives the noise spectral density figures sampled for frequencies 0.1Hz, 1Hz, 10Hz and 100Hz in this 0.1Hz < f < 100Hz range (table rendered following the datasheet):

```
[total root mean squared noise] in band [0.1Hz<f<100Hz]: 12.5μgrms 
Noise Spectral Density 
@0.1Hz 4.4μg/√Hz  
@1Hz 2.0μg/√Hz  
@10Hz 1.5μg/√Hz
@100Hz 1.1μg/√Hz
```

This table gives us the opportunity to discuss how these parameters are related.

First, the total root mean squared noise for a frequency band is a square root from noise power spectral density integrated over the frequency:
$$
{\text {RMS}}_{noise} = \sqrt{\int_{f_{low}}^{f_{high}}N_P(f)df}
$$
Notice that the table gives noise **amplitude** spectral density values, \$N_A(f)\$ in \$m/s^2/\sqrt {\text {Hz}}\$ units. When calculating \$\text {RMS}_{noise}\$, we integrate noise **power** spectral density, \$N_P(f)=N_A^2(f)\$ in \$m^2/s^4/\text {Hz}\$ units, so the resulting \$\text {RMS}_{noise}\$ is in \$m/s^2\$ units, as required for the standard deviation units.

This definition makes it clear that, in general, the noise power spectral density cannot be restored from the root mean squared noise calculated or measured for a frequency band: \$\text {RMS}_{noise}\$ is a single quantity, while \$N_A(f)\$ should be given for every frequency value in the frequency band. We can make this conversion only if we know the law of noise power distribution over frequency. For example, the noise can be constant (independent of frequency), in which case the spectral density can be simply multiplied by the square root of the frequency range value in order to calculate the root mean squared noise.

The noise power spectral density of our example sensor varies with frequency and the values are given only for four frequencies. We cannot compute \$\text {RMS}_{noise}\$ exactly, but we can estimate its value with numerical integration. We divide the frequency band into four frequency ranges: 0<f<0.1Hz, 0.1Hz<f<1Hz, 1Hz<f<10Hz, 10Hz<f<100Hz and assign noise spectral density values for each range equal to the noise spectral density value at the ranges' upper frequencies. The computed value will be underestimated, because the noise power spectral density values decrease with frequency.
$$
\text {TOTALNOISEPOWER} = \sum_i N_A^2(i)·(f_{high}(i)-f_{low}(i))= \\(4.4)^2·0.1+2^2·0.9+1.5^2·9+1.1^2·90=134.69 \\
\text {RMS} = \sqrt {\text{TOTALNOISEPOWER}}=11.6
$$
Somewhat less than 12.5ug given in the datasheet.

Summing up, you can calculate the noise density from the "output noise in (m/s) for the 100Hz" only if you know the law of the noise density distribution. For example, if it is constant, can can simply divide the "output noise for the 100Hz" by the square root of the frequency range value (100Hz).

But have one more look at your datasheet. While not specifying the noise power spectral density under this name, the document may specify the **velocity random walk** parameter in \$m/s/\sqrt {\text {Hz}}\$ units, like the IMU sensor on page 29 of [the STMicroelectronics presentation](https://www.st.com/content/dam/AME/2019/developers-conference-2019/presentations/STDevCon19_7.4_Precise-Vehicle-Positioning.pdf). Knowing statistics of random walk stochastic processes and that the acceleration is a derivative of velocity, you can arrive at the value expressed in the \$m/s^2/\sqrt {\text {Hz}}\$ units required for your MATLAB model.

Comment: Nice answer. Is it possible that a power 2 is missing in the equation \$N_P(f) = N_A(f)\$?

Comment: Absolutely right. Thank you for correction